# Converting a data frame - Python

Tags: python

My data are in a data frame. It looks like this.

[image]

I am trying to convert the data frame into the following format:

[image]

Currently I'm doing this conversion using the following Python codes, which are tedious.

```
def f(row):
    if row['d1'] == 1:
        return 1
    if row['d1'] == 2:
        return ''
    if row['d1'] == 3:
        return ''
    if row['d1'] == 4:
        return ''
    else:
        return ''
    return np.nan

df['t1']=df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Padraic, I edited my post. Is this what you need?

Comment: Hi Kevin, 
Could you please explain what df['t1']=df.apply(f, axis=1) does?

Comment: It read the value in d1 column and insert "1" into t1 column (if the value in d1 is 1). My code is poor. That's why I was looking for better codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could apply following function:

```
def func(x):
    x.iloc[x.iloc[0]] = 1
    return x

In [66]: df
Out[66]: 
   d1  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
0   5   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   0
2   3   0   0   0   0   0
3   4   0   0   0   0   0
4   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   2   0   0   0   0   0

In [67]: df.apply(func, axis=1)
Out[67]: 
   d1  t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
0   5   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   0   0   0   0
2   3   0   0   1   0   0
3   4   0   0   0   1   0
4   1   1   0   0   0   0
5   2   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help